# Query Optimization for Oracle to select single row from multiple views

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple tables a key of `ACCOUNT_ID`,
I have built multiple views to calculate various values for each `CUSTOMER`.

Now I am trying to traverse the relation:

EDIT: Given an svc_mrt_id, on account_id can be identified in CUS_SERVICE, then using the account_id, various statistics can be retrieved.

I tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM CUS_SERVICE s 
    LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER c ON s.account_id = c.account_id
    LEFT JOIN V_STCLOSE_5_CURRENT_BALANCE cb ON cb.stat_account_id = s.account_id
    LEFT JOIN V_STATUS_ALL sa ON sa.account_id = s.account_id
    LEFT JOIN V_NEXT_POOL_DATE pd ON pd.pool_donor = s.account_id
) WHERE svc_mrt_id = ?;


Query plan:
SELECT (245709)
    HASH JOIN (245078)
        HASH JOIN (628)
            NESTED LOOPS
                TABLE CUS_SERVICE (1)
                VIEW V_STATUS_ALL (626)
            VIEW V_STATUS_ALL (626)
/* This one is the culprit, should be (4317) if pushed predicates */
        VIEW V_STCLOSE_5_CURRENT_BALANCE (245078)
            HASH JOIN(232729)
                MAT_VIEW ACCESS(4)
                VIEW (232670)
/* Not pushing this predicate further is completely wrong */
/* Filtering here will generate large intermediate result set for only one row*/
/* Should be pushed to base table to generate only that one row required */
                    FILTER PREDICATES t1.ACCOUNT_ID = s.ACCOUNT_ID
```

The predicates now is pushed only to V_STATUS_ALL but not V_STCLOSE_5_CURRENT_BALANCE when two views are joined together with table CUS_SERVICE

Does anyone know if it is possible to fix this, or have any alternative to this?

Further informations:

Edit: 2013/12/26 19:13 GMT+8
I've isolated two views that are incompatible after some further testing. Here is the result:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT sa.account_id
    FROM V_STCLOSE_5_CURRENT_BALANCE cb
    LEFT JOIN V_STATUS_ALL sa ON sa.account_id = cb.stat_account_id
) WHERE account_id = ?;
/* COST = 4323 */

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT s.svc_mrt_id
    FROM CUS_SERVICE s 
    LEFT JOIN V_STCLOSE_5_CURRENT_BALANCE cb ON cb.stat_account_id = s.account_id
) WHERE svc_mrt_id = ?;
/* COST = 4322, looks right */

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT s.svc_mrt_id
    FROM CUS_SERVICE s
    LEFT JOIN V_STATUS_ALL sa ON sa.account_id = s.account_id
) WHERE svc_mrt_id = ?;
/* COST ~ 2045 */

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT s.svc_mrt_id
    FROM CUS_SERVICE s
    LEFT JOIN V_STCLOSE_5_CURRENT_BALANCE cb ON cb.stat_account_id = s.account_id
    LEFT JOIN V_STATUS_ALL sa ON sa.account_id = s.account_id
) WHERE svc_mrt_id = ?;
/* cost ~ 232729, something strange happened about this 3-Table join combination */
```

For the view query:

```
/*IV_STCLOSE_1_1_T*/
/*IV_STCLOSE_1_2_T*/
/*IV_STCLOSE_2_1_T*/
/*These are materialized view for the bill day related logic,
basically calculate the open and close dates for each customer each month,
and is only refreshed once per day*/


/*IV_STCLOSE_2_2_T*/
/*This filter some unnecessary, outdated transaction records*/
/*As each customer may have only 20/3M transaction records required for calculation,
the query must push select of account_id up to here to be most selective*/
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, POINT_DATE, POINT
FROM history_point 
WHERE point_date >= ( 
    SELECT MIN(open_date) 
    FROM IV_STCLOSE_2_1_t
)

/*IV_STCLOSE_3_T*/
/*This sum points within each month*/
SELECT p0.account_id, p0.open_date, p0.close_date,
COALESCE(SUM(DECODE(SIGN(p.point),-1,p.point)),0) AS point_used,
COALESCE(SUM(DECODE(SIGN(p.point),1,p.point)),0) AS point_earned 
FROM iv_stclose_2_1_t p0 
LEFT JOIN iv_stclose_2_2_t p
ON p.account_id = p0.account_id 
AND p.point_date >=  p0.open_date 
AND p.point_date < p0.close_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY
GROUP BY p0.account_id, p0.open_date, p0.close_date


/*IV_STCLOSE_4_T*/
/*This sums each month's point earned and used for the open and close balance*/
SELECT v.account_id AS STAT_ACCOUNT_ID, v.open_date, v.close_date, 
v.close_balance + t1.open_balance AS open_balance,
t1.point_earned AS point_earn, t1.point_used,
v.close_balance + t1.open_balance + t1.point_earned + t1.point_used AS close_balance
FROM IV_STCLOSE_2_1_T v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT v1.account_id, v1.open_date, v1.point_earned, v1.point_used,
    COALESCE(sum(v2.point_used + v2.point_earned),0) AS OPEN_BALANCE
    FROM IV_STCLOSE_3_T v1 
    LEFT JOIN IV_STCLOSE_3_T v2 
    ON v1.account_id = v2.account_id 
    AND v1.OPEN_DATE > v2.OPEN_DATE
    GROUP BY v1.account_id, v1.open_date, v1.point_earned, v1.point_used
) t1
ON v.account_id = t1.account_id 
AND v.OPEN_DATE = t1.OPEN_DATE


/*V_STCLOSE_5_CURRENT_BALANCE*/
/*This select the most recent balance*/
SELECT v.STAT_ACCOUNT_ID,v.OPEN_DATE,v.CLOSE_DATE,
v.OPEN_BALANCE,v.POINT_EARN,v.POINT_USED,v.CLOSE_BALANCE 
FROM IV_STCLOSE_4_T v 
WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), v.OPEN_DATE) < 1
```

Comment: Please stop using the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) in favor of using explicit joins.  For one thing, it makes it easy to spot accidental cross joins (or throw a syntax error).  Do you really need _all_ columns?  It's usually best to specify exactly which ones.  And why the subselect?  It's not like `svc_mrt_id` is coming from more than one table...  Maybe show us query strings for the views as well?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks for the reminder, I will fix the column issue afterwards as I need quite a large number of columns there.

Comment: Are the tables analyzed, and what sort of indexes/partitions do you have?

Comment: @EvilTeach I had executed DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS using DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE. I added index for each table with account_id(or equivalent) column not set as primary key, and it is not partitioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index hint so the optimizer will use that particular index.  You could also try listing the tables in the order in which they should be joined and then add the /*+ ordered */ hint.

Comment: I've tried /*+ ORDERED */, the CBO of oracle 11g was tricky. If I include ONLY current_balance, it does push select; and if I exclude ONLY current_balance, it also push; but if I include all, it changed its mind and decided not to push select, the order of those views makes no difference, only the combination.